# Mandelbrot set, inequality proof

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

If I have the relation $z_{n+1} = z_{n}^2 + c$. How can I show that $|z_{n+1}| > k |z_n|$ for some $k>1$, if $|z_n| > |c| > 2$? I have no idea how to proof this, any help will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You have $|z_{n+1}| \ge |z_n|^2-|c|\gt |z_n|(|c|-1)$

Comment: I can't see form where you get the first part of the inequality. I understood that k = |c| - 1, but I don't get the rest.

Comment: It is the triangle inequality applied to the complex modulus function.